# Browse Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS Filesystem from a Ubuntu 17.04 Desktop

Tags: networking, server, filesystem, filemanager

I am afraid my Linux experience is very limited. Although not afraid to try new things ;)

I have setup a 16.04 LTS Server and setup a few services.

I would like to be able to browse the Server OS from my 17.04 Desktop. I have tried the other locations and trying the server IP but nothing ever happens.

I can see my Windows based servers and shares as expected.

My requirements ideally would be that I can use a GUI to browse files from the Server itself.

I did a bit of a google but did not find anything obvious.

Thanks in advance for helping this n00b.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to access Ubuntu Server files, [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) is the best program out there.

If you want to access Ubuntu Server terminal, try setting up an SSH Server. Ubuntu has SSH Enabled by default. All you need to do is find your server's IP via "nmap":

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.x.0/24
```

where 'x' is your network, where your devices are connected (Most common is 192.168.1.0)

You can use `ifconfig` and search for "inet address".

Then, do `ssh username@ip` replacing username with your server's username and ip with the server's ip in order to connect to your server. It will ask for a password. Write the password of the server's user. Hope i heped.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input would FileZilla allow me to browse the whole disk?

SSH is enabled as I setup most of the sever externally via Putty. 

I have the IP of the server, Is there someway to use SSH with a GUI interface to view file like text, images etc?

Comment: I personally use  "nano", in order to edit text files/configurations. It's a terminal application that makes editing via terminal very easy. Since you want to open GUI applications via SSH, you need to enable X11 Forwarding [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely). Since, setting up X11Forward may be confusing for you, i suggest opening Text Files and Images via **FileZilla** or via Ubuntu's "connect to server" tab on Files (nautilus). Here is a screenshot: [link](https://i.imgur.com/myPO6mS.png)